# Image not showing up in itextsharp generated html to pdf document when Height/Width are added in style

Tags: pdf, itext

I am working on dynamic HTML to PDF document and using ckeditor to write HTML and then itextsharp 5.5.10 to generate downloadable PDF from it. Below is the code I am using

```
string htmlText = "some basic HTML I wrote in ckeditor 4.0 and save in my DB to retrieve later"


StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlText);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 18f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);


// instantiate the custom PdfPageEventHelper
MyPageEventHandler e = new MyPageEventHandler()
     {
    ImageHeader = imageHeader
};
writer.PageEvent = e;

pdfDoc.Open();
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
pdfDoc.Close();

// Auto Download option
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Proposal-" + pid + ".pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Now everything is working fine, thanks to this great library itextsharp however sometimes its not adding few images to PDF file.

During debugging I found that variable `htmlText` has same input HTML that I saved using ekeditor and it contains all `img` tags too but still some images are not showing up in PDF.

Below are few tags in my HTML

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.mydomain/fullpath/13101571jjc-banner.png" />
<img alt="" src="http://www.mydomain/fullpath/0c1bc6fbchart-1.png" style="width:400px" />
<img alt="" src="http://www.mydomain/fullpath/f7802520graph1.png" style="height:288px; width:643px" />
<img alt="" src="http://www.mydomain/fullpath/4cd70c03sample_s-l_DISTRIBUTION.jpg" style="height:756px; width:1056px" />
```

and **4th image is not showing up** in my PDF.**

I understand that it may have something to do with `Height` and `Width` attribute on `img` tag but I am not able to solve it.

Note : image show up properly when I remove either `Height` or `Width` or both attributes from `img` tag. But actual user using my code won't do that every time they add a new image in HTML so I am looking for a proper solution here.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion and solution.

Comment: Are you sure it's a .jpg while the rest is .png?

Comment: *"width:1056px"* - that's wider than an A4 page, isn't it? Thus, that image simply does not fit into your document.

Comment: Also: why are you using a *maintenance* release of iText (the iText 5 series are being abandoned, and so is XML Worker) while iText 7 has much better HTML to PDF support with the [pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML). You won't have to rewrite much code to upgrade; on the contrary: you'll just have to remove plenty of code lines. See the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). It will be hard to find voluntary support for XML Worker, so please use iText 7 + pdfHTML instead of iText 5 + XML Worker.

Comment: @h_matze_h yes its jpg and others are png.

Comment: @mkl I see that its large image but lib works very fine with larger images without that Width attribute in Style. But as I said actual user using my code won't do that every time they add a new image in HTML and ckeditor add those attibute from default image size.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , thank you for this wonderful library.I am new to this and at time of starting project I found related demos in itext 5.5 version and it was working fine with me too so I used it. Now I can work on migrating it as I get some more time to work on it ORnow if it solves the current issue I am facing ? Please suggest best approach.

Comment: If you say "width:1056px" in your style attribute, you indicate that you want the image to show at that width. And as an A4 page does not have that width, that cannot be done. If the current tools used in your workflow create such show-stopping attributes, they might not be appropriate ones. Alternatively you can first parse the HTML files, check them for inappropriate attributes, and fix them.

Comment: I concur with what @mkl says.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) i'll work accordingly now.

Comment: Ok, I'll make the comments an answer.

Comment: What should be the max-width and max-height of an image in order to get it printed correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand the `style` attribute of your problem image looks like this:

```
style="height:756px; width:1056px"
```

On the other hand you use an A4 sized document

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 18f);
```

and an A4 page has a width of about 8.27in which at 96px per inch are about 794px.

Thus, an A4 page simply is not width enough for a 1056px wide image!

So to accommodate the image you can either

- change the document size to something wider, or
- before feeding the HTML into iTextSharp apply a preprocessing step which checks it for inappropriate attribute values and fixes them, or
- change the HTML generation process to not produce such inappropriate attribute values to start with.

In an additional comment you asked

> What should be the max-width and max-height of an image in order to get it printed correctly?

Considering that you explicitly set the left, right, and top margin to 0 and the bottom margin to 18 user units (by default a user unit is a 1/72 in), the maximum image width will likely be about 794px and the maximum image height about (1122 - 18 * 96 / 72)px = 1098px. To be sure subtract yet another few pixels.

This of course depends on your HTML not adding additional margins or cell borders or whatever around the image...

Comment: Hey, This can be a totally different issue BUT now when I use images path with https , it doesn't show up in PDF. my domain is using https. Images work well when I use http:// only. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: well, it *is a totally different issue.* And I've no idea immediately what causes it. Thus, please make it a new question in its own right so others may provide input.